# What does it mean when 24 contiguous bytes in a file are corrupted?

Tags: hard-drive, corruption

I copied 500 MB of files from one hard drive to another and four files were found to be corrupted on the destination drive, each with one section that had 24 bytes different from the source.

What would cause each file to have exactly 24 bytes wrong?

Comment: Please see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Thanks, sorry.  Thought the issue causing my previous question to get down votes was that it was too broad.